# The value of a must be 56 but when i run this program i am getting 0

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to test this program on google test but test cases fails. This code is supposed to give me 56 in the output but i am getting 0 in output. where is the mistake? Also tell me about the scope of static variables like how can i access private static variable outside the class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CSR {
private:
    int complaintsResolved;
    static int totalComplaintsResolved;

public:
    void setComplaintsResolved(int cpsResolved)
    {
        if (cpsResolved < 0)
            return;
        complaintsResolved = cpsResolved;
    }
    static void setTotalCpsResolved(int totalCpsResolved)
    {
        totalComplaintsResolved = totalCpsResolved;
    }
    int getComplaintsResolved()
    {
        return complaintsResolved;
    }
    static int getTotalCpsResolved()

    {
        return totalComplaintsResolved;
    }
};
int CSR::totalComplaintsResolved = 0;

void calcTotalComplaints(CSR employees[7])
{
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        a += employees[i].getTotalCpsResolved();
    cout << a;
    CSR::setTotalCpsResolved(a);
}
int main()
{
    CSR employees[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        employees[i].setComplaintsResolved((i + 1) * 2);
    }
    calcTotalComplaints(employees);
}
```

Test Cases

```
TEST(Q5, second)
{
    CSR employees[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        employees[i].setComplaintsResolved((i + 1) * 2);
    }
    calcTotalComplaints(employees);
    ASSERT_EQ(56, CSR::getTotalCpsResolved());
```

Comment: You can't access a `private static` variable directly from outside the class. You can use getters and setters and make them `public static` to access the variable.

Comment: Got you but look into the above given code and tell me why i am not getting 56 in the output. I have made getters and setters to access private static variable?

Comment: "Also tell me about the scope of static variables like how can i access private static variable outside the class". This is what OP wrote in his question.

Comment: Static variables have class level scope. I think we can access the private static variable using getters and setters. This is what i have done in the above code

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

`a += employees[i].getTotalCpsResolved();`

instead of

`a += employees[i].getCpsResolved();`

and since `CSR::totalComplaintsResolved` is initially set to 0 and never changed before accessing `CSR::getTotalCpsResolved` it just keeps adding 0 to `a`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it is giving correct output